# How to create a random float in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, random, floating-point

I'm trying to create a random float between 0.15 and 0.3 in Objective-C. The following code always returns 1:

```
int randn = (random() % 15)+15;
float pscale = (float)randn / 100;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this code seems to be working, still using 100.0f is better.
Only case that I can guess is that you're putting this code in a function and not declaring it in .h, so the compiler could be upgrading it to double.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (float)rand() / RAND_MAX
```

Or to get one between 0 and 5:

```
 float randomNum = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 5;
```

Several ways to do the same thing.

Comment: This is wrong. `random() / RAND_MAX` will not give you a floating-point value as neither value is floating-point. Also, the domain of `random()` is not 0 to RAND_MAX. The domain of `rand()` and `rand_r()` is. So you should use: `(float)rand() / RAND_MAX` to get the expected result.

Comment: This is wrong (rand()/RAND_MAX) will give you a zero. Jonathan's comment is true.

Answer (score 68):

Here is a function

```
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)smallNumber and:(float)bigNumber {
    float diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    return (((float) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;
}
```

Comment: #define boris_random(smallNumber, bigNumber) ((((float) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * (bigNumber - smallNumber)) + smallNumber)

Comment: @chunkyguy, Could you please rewrite this answer using `arc4random_uniform`?

Answer (score 4):

1. use arc4random() or seed your random values
2. try

   ```
   float pscale = ((float)randn) / 100.0f;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me, it produces a random number between 0.15 and 0.3 (provided I seed with `srandom()`). Have you called `srandom()` before the first call to `random()`? You will need to provide `srandom()` with some entropic value (a lot of people just use `srandom(time(NULL))`).

For more serious random number generation, have a look into [`arc4random`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html), which is used for cryptographic purposes. This random number function also returns an integer type, so you will still need to cast the result to a floating point type.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest.

```
+ (float)randomNumberBetween:(float)min maxNumber:(float)max
{
    return min + arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using srandom() and rand() is unsafe when you need true randomizing with some float salt.

On MAC_10_7, IPHONE_4_3 and higher you can use arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)*.
It allows to generate true random integer from zero to *upper_bound*.

So you can try the following

```
u_int32_t upper_bound = <some big enough integer>;

float r = 0.3 * (0.5 + arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)*1.0/upper_bound/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Caladain's answer, if you want the solution to be as easy to use as `rand()`, you can define these:

```
#define randf() ((CGFloat)rand() / RAND_MAX)
#define randf_scaled(scale) (((CGFloat)rand() / RAND_MAX) * scale)
```

Feel free to replace `CGFloat` with `double` if you don't have access to CoreGraphics.

Answer (score -5):

I ended up generating to integers one for the actual integer and then an integer for the decimal. Then I join them in a string then I parse it to a floatvalue with the "floatValue" function... I couldn't find a better way and this works for my intentions, hope it helps :)

```
int integervalue = arc4random() % 2;
int decimalvalue = arc4random() % 9;   
NSString *floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d",integervalue,decimalvalue];
float randomFloat = [floatString floatValue];
```

Comment: This is an amazingly convoluted way to do a simple thing, and it's not even correct. (For example, it could never generate `1.01`.)