# Random range of float in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, random, floating-point

for an in I'm doing this:

```
int randomRange(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min;
    if (range == 0) return min;

    return (arc4random() % range) + min;
 }
```

but how can I do this with a float?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a random float in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410070/how-to-create-a-random-float-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
+(float) randFloatBetween:(float)low and:(float)high
{
    float diff = high - low;
    return (((float) rand() / RAND_MAX) * diff) + low;
}
```

Comment: ok..I just modified it a little bit (now it looks similiar to the randomInt)..thanks.