# Generate Random Numbers Between Two Numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, random, arc4random

I have two text boxes and user can input 2 positive integers (Using Objective-C). The goal is to return a random value between the two numbers.

I've used "man arc4random" and still can't quite wrap my head around it. I've came up with some code but it's buggy.

```
float lowerBound = lowerBoundNumber.text.floatValue;
float upperBound = upperBoundNumber.text.floatValue;
float rndValue;
//if lower bound is lowerbound < higherbound else switch the two around before randomizing.
if(lowerBound < upperBound)
{
    rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*((upperBound-lowerBound)+lowerBound));
}
else 
{
    rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*((lowerBound-upperBound)+upperBound));
}
```

Right now if I put in the values 0 and 3 it seems to work just fine. However if I use the numbers 10 and 15 I can still get values as low as 1.0000000 or 2.000000 for "rndValue".

Do I need to elaborate my algorithm or do I need to change the way I use arc4random?

Comment: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. Delete the open parenthesis after `*` and the close parenthesis before `;`. You still have rounding issues though.

Comment: The general formula `minValue + ((maxValue - minValue) * rnd())` where `rnd()` returns a random floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0 will return the value you're looking for. I leave it to you to convert that into Obj-C and optimize it to suit your needs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:Thanks! That actually did the trick!

Comment: @JimH. Wrong formula. it needs to be `min + (max - min + 1) * rnd()`.

Answer (score 126):

You could simply use integer values like this:

```
int lowerBound = ...
int upperBound = ...
int rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
```

Or if you mean you want to include float number between lowerBound and upperBound? If so please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579457/1265516

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question, please see the updated answer.

Comment: the code does not include the upperBound as the random output, see my answer below as the fix.

Comment: This will generate random integers greater than or equal to `lowerBound`, but less than (but not including) `upperBound`. If you want to include `upperBound` in the range of numbers, you want `rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound + 1)`. Or perhaps better (to eliminate modulo bias), `rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(upperBound - lowerBound + 1)`.

Answer (score 71):

The following code include the minimum **AND MAXIMUM** value as the random output number:

```
- (NSInteger)randomNumberBetween:(NSInteger)min maxNumber:(NSInteger)max
{
    return min + arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)(max - min + 1));
}
```

Update:
I edited the answer by replacing `arc4random() % upper_bound` with `arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)` as @rmaddy suggested.
And here is the reference of [arc4random_uniform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) for the details.

Update2:
I updated the answer by inserting a cast to uint32_t in `arc4random_uniform()` as @bicycle indicated.

Comment: It's even better to use `return arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1) + min;`.

Comment: @rmaddy Why is it better to just return the whole operation rather than equalling that operation to a NSInteger and then returning that NSInteger?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff It's not. Notice the answer has been edit since my comment. The answer used to suggest using `arc4random() % (max - min + 1)`. My comment suggested using `arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1)`.

Comment: I really like your way of realization, elegant and simple, appreciated!

Comment: That gives the annoying implicit conversion loses integer precision warning. Better to put a cast in it:

`return min + arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)(max - min + 1));`

Answer (score 7):

```
-(int) generateRandomNumberWithlowerBound:(int)lowerBound
                               upperBound:(int)upperBound
{
    int rndValue = lowerBound + arc4random() % (upperBound - lowerBound);
    return rndValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid clamping values with mod (%) if you can, because even if the pseudo-random number generator you're using (like `arc4random`) is good at providing uniformly distributed numbers in its full range, it may not provide uniformly distributed numbers within the restricted modulo range.

You also don't need to use a literal like `0x100000000` because there is a convenient constant available in stdint.h:

```
(float)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX
```

That will give you a random float in the interval [0,1].  Note that `arc4random` returns an integer in the interval [0, 2**32 - 1].

To move this into the interval you want, you just add your minimum value and multiply the random float by the size of your range:

```
lowerBound + ((float)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX) * (upperBound - lowerBound);
```

In the code you posted you're multiplying the random float by the whole mess (lowerBound + (upperBound - lowerBound)), which is actually just equal to upperBound.  And that's why you're still getting results less than your intended lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C Function**:

```
-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to
{
    return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

**Swift:**

```
func getRandomNumberBetween(_ from: Int, to: Int) -> Int 
{
    return Int(from) + arc4random() % (to - from + 1)
}
```

**Call it anywhere by**:

```
int OTP = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:99];
NSLog(@"OTP IS %ld",(long)OTP);
NSLog(@"OTP IS %@",[NSString stringWithFormat @"%ld",(long)OTP]);
```

**For Swift:**

```
var OTP: Int = getRandomNumberBetween(10, to: 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift:**

```
let otp = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
```

Try this.