# How do I divide numbers in C?

Tags: c

```
double test3 = 1/7;
NSLog(@"The value of test3 = %1.6f",test3);
```

Result:

`The value of test3 = 0.000000`

Why won't it give me a fraction as a float value? It should say:

`The value of test3 = 0.142857`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do `1.0 / 7.0` or `1 / 7.0` or `1.0 / 7` for the compiler to do floating point division.

`1/7` is simple integer division, which is `0`. Only the result of the integer division is casted and stored in `test3` and if both arguments are integers then you will get an integer returned.

---

To include random numbers (as mentioned in the comments):

To generate a random number between an inclusive lower and an exclusive upper bound do this:

```
int randomNum = lowerBound + arc4random_uniform(upperBound - lowerBound);
```

Note that one should use `arc4random_uniform(x)` (thanks rmaddy!) as it is superior to `arc4random() % x` and `rand() % x`.

Comment: And I have to do, for example, rand()*1.0/rand()*1.0 in order to get that same effect with two variables.

Comment: @Sparky I'm not sure about that, I would explicitly cast them like this: ``(double)rand() / (double)rand()``

Comment: You can actually do just `1/7.0` or `1.0/7`. As long as one value is floating point then you are OK.

Comment: How would I limit that then? I've been using random()&1500 to get a number between 0 and 1500, but that binary expression doesn't accept double values as operands.

Comment: @Sparky ``random() & 1500`` does not return a "fair" random number between 0 and 1500. Doing ``<lowerBound> + random() % (<upperBound> - <lowerBound>)`` generates a random number between the lower and upper bound as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678373/generate-random-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-objective-c) question. Note that the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive. Also note that using ``arc4random()`` is better because it is superior to ``rand()``.

Comment: And it's better to use `arc4random_uniform(X)` instead of `arc4random() % X`.