# UIView animate random

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i want to animate my image with random duration, and random delay. help me please. I'm beginner. here is the code:

```
-(void)up
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        mole.center = CGPointMake(63, 210);
    }];


    [self performSelector:@selector(down) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
 }
```

So, i need "0.3" from duration and 1.0 from delay to be random. like, between 0.0 and 1.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)smallNumber and:(float)bigNumber {
    float diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    return (((float) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;
}
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410070/how-to-create-a-random-float-in-objective-c).

You would call it like this:

```
[self randomFloatBetween:0.0 and:1.0];
```

Comment: Technically speaking that is not a function it is a method. It would probably make more sense as a function as I am sure it does not need to belong to a particular class.